# Is it possible to add GIF to open layers 3 map?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, openlayers, gif

I have one question. In past we just used open layers 2 and it used svg and we had some GIF markups on map (fire animations etc). Now we have open layers 3 map which use canvas to render the map. Is it now possible to still add GIF markups to the new map?

Now when I add a GIF, I just get only one "slide" from the GIF - it doesn't have animations.

What is the best way to do it? Render some SVG in canvas (how) or "refresh" the GIF element?

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here... I really don't want to do something like having separate images by each frame and change those with a timer.

Comment: Ok, now I'm working on it. So when I get some info how to do it, I will write here.

Comment: Ok I will try to do something with overlay. When feature (point) will be initializing on map I will check that has it gif icon or not. When it will be a gif I will create overlay with this GIF and display above this point. I will try to implement it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have completed this task :-) YES - it's possible to add a GIF with motion as icon to the point on map, but it requires some JS code.

I've done it with **Overlays**. And the hint is `precompose` event, which is fired on every time when something on map has been changed (very very often).

On this event we check which **Feature** has an icon with `.gif` extension (we can flag features before when we create Features).

If has, we check that overlay with this id exist:

1. if YES - just only change position of this overlay (coordinates of
   feature)
2. if NOT - create new overlay with parameters like
   coordinates, id of feature. Of course also create element on map

And remember to **remove redundant overlays** (when points are not visible in extent, or when we change the map or hide the layer).

Comment: Finally I made it with overlays too, but I don't have to worry about changes in render, here I have an example: https://jsfiddle.net/jolmos/hmag2xww  In my real code, I recieve the positions of the features by ajax and I create the elements(the gifs) with JS (depending on what I get from ajax).